# F1-score giving good value on imbalanced dataset.

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis

If I have an imbalanced dataset that consists of 90% positive points and 10% negative points. Now I created a "dumb" model which always predicts every point as a positive point.
The confusion matrix of this problem will be  -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMunS.png)

Now the Precision of the above confusion matrix will be -

Precision = No. of true positive out of the number of points predicted positive by the model.

So, Precision = TP / (TP + FP) = 90 / (90 + 10) = 0.9

And Recall will be -

Recall = No. of true positive out of the number of points that are actually positive.

So, Recall = TP / (TP + FN) = 90 / (90 + 0) = 1.0

As we can see both precision and recall are high
and F1score of this model is,

F1-Score = PR / P + R * 2 = 0.94

This is a high score, so according to this, the model is very good.
How can the f1 score give good results on an imbalanced dataset?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your $F_1$ score is *high* because both precision and recall (for the *positive* class) are *high*. Note that $F_1$ is specific to one (positive) class (in a binary classification problem). In a multiclass problem you would need to calculate precision and recall for each class separately and then aggregate them.

Try, in your example, to calculate the recall of the *negative* class (this is referred to as *true negative rate/specificity*):

$$
TNR = \frac{TN}{N} = 0
$$
i.e. your model is unable to recognize (recall) any of the *negative* samples. Imagine if you "swapped" the labels (*positive* class with *negative* class) and classified all of your samples as *negative* - your model's accuracy would still be 90% but your $F1$ score would be zero.